# Swift Protocols: hiding some properties

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I would like to create a `trimmedText` property for `UITextView` and `UITextField`. Here is what I did:

```
protocol TrimmedTextSupporting: class {
  var _text: String? { get }
  var trimmedText: String { get }
}

extension TrimmedTextSupporting {
  var trimmedText: String {
    let text = self._text ?? ""
    return text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
  }
}

extension UITextField: TrimmedTextSupporting {

  var _text: String? {
    return self.text
  }
}

extension UITextView: TrimmedTextSupporting {

  var _text: String? {
    return self.text
  }
}
```

I need `_text` property because `text` is declared as `String?` in `UITextField` and as `String!` in `UITextView` (whyyyy?! >_<). Now I would like to hide this property to avoid cluttering the API.

Here's what I tried:

1) Marking it as `private`. The compiler doesn't allow this: `'private' modifier cannot be used in protocols`

2) Separating it into a private protocol:

```
private protocol TextExposing {
  var _text: String? { get }
}

extension UITextField: TextExposing {
  var _text: String? {
    return self.text
  }
}

extension UITextView: TextExposing {
  var _text: String? {
    return self.text
  }
}

///////

protocol TrimmedTextSupporting: class {
  var trimmedText: String { get }
}

extension UITextField: TrimmedTextSupporting {}

extension UITextView: TrimmedTextSupporting {}

extension TrimmedTextSupporting where Self: TextExposing {

  // compiler error
  var trimmedText: String {
    let text = self._text ?? ""
    return text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
  }
}
```

But compiler complains again:
`Property 'trimmedText' must be declared internal because it matches a requirement in internal protocol 'TrimmedTextSupporting'`

I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be inclined to go with:

```
protocol TrimmedTextSupporting: class {
    var trimmedText: String { get }
}

extension TrimmedTextSupporting {

    private func trimText(text: String) -> String {
        return text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    }
}

extension UITextField: TrimmedTextSupporting {

    var trimmedText: String {
        return trimText(text ?? "")
    }
}

extension UITextView: TrimmedTextSupporting {

    var trimmedText: String {
        return trimText(text ?? "")
    }
}
```

So you've avoided duplicating the hard work by doing it in a shared and private function, and the extensions on `UITextField` and `UITextView` do the minimum they need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `TrimmedTextSupporting` as an internal Protocol.  If you don't want to declare `trimmedText` as `internal`, declare `TrimmedTextSupporting` as a private protocol:

```
private protocol TrimmedTextSupporting: class {
    var trimmedText: String { get }
}
```

This compiles fine.

```
let textView = UITextView()
textView.text = "hello  "
print(textView.trimmedText) // "hello"

let textField = UITextField()
textField.text = "  world "
print(textField.trimmedText) // "world"
```

Comment: are properties of `TrimmedTextSupporting` protocol available outside of the file if it is declared as private?

Comment: @deville No, it would have to be in the same file...  I see your issue now.  Let me go and keep working on a better answer.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can let trimmedText is not required, set to optional.

(if you wanna use optional in Swift, you should let protocol to be @objc)

```
@objc protocol TrimmedTextSupporting: class {
     optional var trimmedText: String { get }
}
```